# How to persist a JPA field as a clob?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've a class that doesn't serialize very well to a relational entity. As so, I'd like to persist it using JPA as a CLOB (I can serialize it to a String). How would I do this using JPA?

Example Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class Foo {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String simpleString;
   private Bar bar;
}
```

Bar is the class that I'd like persisted as a CLOB inside MY_TABLE.

Comment: *How* can you serialize it to a String?

Answer (score 9):

You could annotate the string with `javax.persistence.Lob`.

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private String simpleString;
```

See [`Lob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) Javadoc:

> Specifies that a persistent property or field should be persisted as a large object to a database-supported large object type.
>   Portable applications should use the Lob annotation when mapping to a database Lob type. The Lob annotation may be used in conjunction with the `Basic` annotation or the `ElementCollection` annotation when the element collection value is of basic type. A Lob may be either a binary or character type.
>
> The `Lob` type is inferred from the type of the persistent field or property, and except for string and character-based types defaults to Blob.

Next, you could set the `Bar` field to `transient` so it's not persisted:

```
@Transient
private Bar bar
```

Then in your `Bar` getter, you could deserialise it if required:

```
public Bar getBar()
{
  if (this.bar == null)
  {
    this.bar = deserialise(this.simpleString);
  }

  return this.bar;
}
```

Thread safety is left as an exercise for the reader.

Additionally, you could also use [`@PrePersist`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) to serialise `Bar` into its string form if you needed to do this immediately prior to persisting.

Answer (score 4):

**I had a similar problem like you** where I needed to store a JSON in a field so when I used BLOB I was causing myself a lot of unnecessary headaches.
You are using blob for a content kind of data, I respectfully advise you to use CLOB for data **if** it's in Character format.

to wrap my answer up, **if** you are using the *ORACLE* database(which is a database that always causes problems of speaking its language) use bellow format as a guide or best practice, which is based on oracle documentation itself, to solve your problem:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)
@Column(name="REPORT")
protected String report;
```

to retrieve data or persist data you can use spring Crudrepository
and use `save` and `findall` methods.

Good luck!