# Unable to get an Oracle connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbc-odbc, ojdbc

Unable to get an Oracle connection.

I am using the following piece of code in order to get an oracle connection in a custom smart service plugin :-

```
public static Connection openNewConnection(String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return connection;
}
```

It works perfectly fine as a standalone, but when used inside JBoss, it gives `"ClassCastExcepton"` with the following message :-

> ClassCastException : "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast
>   to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection".

I have used this with `ojdbc5.jar`, `ojdbc6.jar`, `ojdbc7.jar` and `ojdbc14.jar` files respectively.

Any clues to this issue ?

Comment: This may help you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483356/connection-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection

Answer (score 0):

According to "Display Name is missing's" answer on this [Error casting T4CConnection to OracleConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281407/error-casting-t4cconnection-to-oracleconnection) , ojdbcN.jar causes a conflict that you have to resolve by re-referencing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The class `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` extends the class `oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection`, which in turn implements the interface `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`. So it would seem that the cast should succeed.

The reason it does not can only be a class loader problem, i.e. there are two jar files with the same classes involved or more specifically: ojdbcN.jar is on the class path twice, most likely somewhere in the JBoss installation in in your .ear/.war file. And the cast fails because the source and target class and interfaces are in two different jar files.

Fix your class path. For JBoss, `ojdbc7.jar` needs to go into a shared JBoss directory and must not be included in your .war or .ear file.