# ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jboss7.x

When I am trying to get connection with an Oracle database, I am facing this issue. My application specs are java8 + ejb + jboss-eap-7.3 + oracle 12c

Please find my code details below

My pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
         <version>14</version>
         <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope> 
    <dependency>
```

I have added "ojdbc6.jar" in module.xml file from the path `jboss-ep-7.3/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc/main`.

```
    My DBConnection.java

    CallableStatement statement;
    Connection connection;
    ArrayDescriptor descriptor;
    Connection conn = datasourceObj.getconnection(dev);
    try {
        statement = conn.prepareCall(callString);
        connection = ((WrappedConnection) 
      conn).getUnderlyingConnection();
        descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("NUM_ARRAY", 
       connection);
    }
```

After deployed this EAR into jboss 7.3, I got the below error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast
> to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

And I replace the below code

```
connection = ((WrappedConnection) conn).getUnderlyingConnection();
```

with this piece of code

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) conn.getClass().getMethod("getUnderlyingConnection").invoke(conn);
```

After this code change am getting

> ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to
> oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

I checked even removing the classes12.jar but no progress on that. The same I need to do for oracle19c. Please give your valuable comments to sort out this.

Comment: Why are you getting the underlying connection, rather than just doing `OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) conn;` ?

Comment: ojdbc6 => implies it should be used with Java6. For Java8 use ojdbc8. PS: classes12 is meant for Java 1.2

Comment: @AlexPoole even i tried the same but the result is 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Comment: @ibre5041 Still same issue
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Comment: Is `NUM_ARRAY` a [VARRAY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-E932FC04-C7AD-4562-9555-8BA05446C0B8)? Are you trying to map a java object to a VARRAY or vice-versa, i.e. map a VARRAY to a java object? Maybe you should describe what you want to achieve rather than ask how to fix the bug in your implementation? However if you insist on using your implementation, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571100/unable-to-get-an-oracle-connection

Comment: @Abra  The actual implementation is ,looping the storedprocedure values and the return string is equals to an array means adding into Array to present in the view page.
Please find the below code ref :
for(Param parm: storedProcedureObj.getInParams()) {
       if("long[]".equals(param.getType()) {
           ArrayDescriptor descriptor= ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("NUM_ARRAY", 
       connection);
           ARRAY  arObj = new ARRAY(descriptor, connection, name);
}
}
For java 6 it's working fine but java 8 exception throwing

Comment: Don't add question details in a comment. [edit] your question and add those details that appear in your comment.